# Using differentials to find the percentual error on calculating the volume of a cube

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am given the following problem:

> The size of a cube measures $20 \, \rm{cm}$ with a percentage error of $\pm
>  2 \%$. Use differentials to estimate the error on calculating its
>   volume.

What I have so far is

$$2 \% \cdot 20 \, \rm{cm} = 0.4 \, \rm{cm}$$

$$V = l^3 \Rightarrow V' = 3l^2 l'\\
V' = 3 \cdot 400 \cdot 0.4\\
V' = 480 \, \rm{cm}^3\\
E_{\%} = \frac{480}{20^3} = 0.06 = 6 \%
$$

Is that correct or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you use differentials? [result looks OK but just think differentials were asked to be used in process]

Comment: @coffeemath if you read $dV/dt$ instead of $V'$ (and the same for the other variable) it should be ok right?

Comment: It may be useful to include units in writing out the third line. Also, it's not really sensible to say that $V'=\dfrac{dV}{dt}=400$ cm^3: if $t$ is intended as a _time_ then $\dfrac{dV}{dt}$ should have units of cm^3 per second. What you probably mean is not $\dfrac{dV}{dt}$ but just $dV$.

Comment: Yes, but maybe "move the dt to the other side" of equation like $dV=3s^2ds$ where $s$ is the cube's side length. Then the usual way is at that point replace $ds$ by the small difference in $s.$

Comment: I see. What I actually meant was $dV/dl$. Thank you for the explanation. best regards!

Comment: That doesn't really fix the issue: $dV/dl$ would have units of cm^3 / cm = cm^2 not cm^3. (Sure, @coffeemath, that works.)

Comment: You have asked many questions on a very similar topic. If you are confused about differentials, I recommend you ask a questions about the concepts that are confusing, rather than asking a new question for each problem on your problem set.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the binomial theorem. If $|x| \ll 1$, then

$$(1 + x)^n = 1 + \binom{n}{1} x + \binom{n}{2} x^2 + \cdots + \binom{n}{n} x^n \approx 1 + n x$$

Hence,

$$\left(20 \cdot (1+0.02)\right)^3 = 20^3  \cdot (1+0.02)^3 \approx 20^3 \cdot (1 + 3 \cdot 0.02) = 20^3 \cdot (1 + 0.06)$$

A perturbation of $2\%$ in the side of the cube produces a perturbation of approximately $6\%$ in its volume. One can use the same argument to conclude that the perturbation in the surface area of the cube is approximately $4\%$.